# Closed and deleted banner layout is too big

Tags: bug, design

The banner for [closed questions and deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877121/is-there-a-free-browser-based-uml-modelling-tool) is too wide in the new layout.  I didn't notice this on a [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797968/sql-split-comma-seprated-column-values-and-apply-in-operator) that isn't deleted, but you can see it on a deleted question.

[This question demonstrates the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877121/is-there-a-free-browser-based-uml-modelling-tool) (10k only):

> [image]

There is an overhang of the banner, either the deleted question color needs to be expanded to the full width of the table or the banner needs to be reduced.

I'm seeing this in Firefox and Chrome for a Mac.

Comment: looks like a post it note.

Comment: The issues also exists using FF or IE on Windows. Less noticeable on non-deleted questions there as well. BTW: It's not restricted to main, meta is also affected.

Comment: A fix for this is pending, but it has implications I want Jin's eyes on first since it may break other things. I'll get this deployed soon as we can.